# How do I display HTML or XML in an HTML document unrendered?

Tags: asp.net, html, xml

I need to send XML/HTML in an HTML email so that it displays unrendered.  I'm using ASP.NET.  What is the approach I should take?

Comment: Replace all the '<' characters with &lt;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Encode it. You can use the [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the HTML to be displayed as text and not interpreted. If so, then you can simply use the Server.HtmlEncode method to encode your string and then send that back to the browser.

```
...
text="<h1>Hello World</h1>";
textEncoded = Server.HtmlEncode(text);
...

<%=textEncoded%>
```